Integration of a function on an embedded Riemannian Manifold
Consider a manifold $M_\varepsilon$ given by the following embedding in $\mathbb{R}^3$
$$
\varphi(t,\theta) = (t\cos\theta, t\sin\theta, t),
$$
with $t\geq\varepsilon$ and $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. The metric induced by the standard metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the matrix form becomes
$$
g = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & t^2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
so that the volume form is $d\text{vol}_g = tdt\wedge d\theta$.
Consider a function $f$ on $M_\varepsilon$, where $f\in L^2(M_\varepsilon,d\text{vol}_g)$. Let us say I have the following integral:
\begin{align*}
\int_{M_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{t^2}\partial_\theta f \ d\text{vol}_g
\end{align*}
What does this become in local coordinates?

I am unsure what the goal of the calculation is, since it is already formulated in terms of the local coordinates $(t,\theta)$. I would start by plugging in the volume form and the definitions of the expressions in the integral.

Does it become $\int_{M_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{t^2} \partial_\theta f \text{vol}g = \int{\varphi^{-1}(M_\varepsilon)} \frac{1}{t} \partial_{\theta}f dtd\theta$? I am trying to understand how the $d\text{vol}g$ affects the coefficient $\frac{1}{t^2}$ when I write the integral $\int{M_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{t^2} \partial_\theta f d\text{vol}_g$ as a double integral $\int\int tdtd\theta$.

The exterior algebra of differential forms is a $C^{\infty}(M_\varepsilon)$-module when viewed as smooth sections of a vector bundle, or if you want "pointwise $\mathbb{R}$-linear". So $\frac{1}{t^2} (t dt\wedge d\theta) = \frac{1}{t} dt\wedge d\theta$. You can also express $\partial_{\theta} f$ as a function of $(t,\theta)$, that might help.

Disclaimer: I myself often find this "short hand" in notation confusing if you want to apply the definitions rigorously, but I understand its usefulness. I will try to explain the notation and calculation.
What might cause confusion is that both the coefficient function of your differential form as well as the integrand are already expressed in terms of the coordinate chart, but your integral itself is written as an integral over the manifold.
First of all: Your parametrization is not bijective, so we have to exclude for example the set $\{(t,2\pi)\}$ from the domain,but this is a set of Lebesgue-measure $0$.
Now we can explicitly write out our integrand: Our integral is of the form
$$\int\limits_{M_\varepsilon} f \ d\operatorname{vol}_g $$ with
$$(f\circ \varphi)(t,\theta) = \frac{1}{t^2}\cdot ((d_\theta f)\circ\varphi)(t,\theta)$$ and
$$(d\operatorname{vol}_g \circ \varphi )(t,\theta)= t (dt\wedge d\theta)_{\varphi(t,\theta)} = , $$
so $\varphi^* d\operatorname{vol}_g = t dt\wedge d\theta$ (a differential form in $\mathbb{R}^n$, here $dt$ and $d\theta$ just encode the dual to the standard basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$).
Now all expressions are already "pulled back" to the domain of the chart in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is handy, but confusing if you want to apply the definitions of the integral since the step of pulling back to Euclidian space is already done. Writing this out, we get
$$\int\limits_{M_\varepsilon} f \ d\operatorname{vol}_g = \int\limits_{\varphi^{-1}(M_\varepsilon)} (f\circ \varphi) \ \varphi^*(d\operatorname{vol}_g) = \int\limits_{\{(t,\theta): t \geq \varepsilon, 0\leq \theta < 2\pi\}} \frac{1}{t^2}\frac{\partial(f\circ\varphi)}{\partial \theta} \cdot t \ dt\wedge d\theta$$
$$ = \int\limits_{\varepsilon}^\infty \frac{1}{t} \left(\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\partial (f\circ\varphi)}{\partial \theta} d\theta\right) \ dt =\int\limits_{\varepsilon}^\infty \frac{1}{t} \left(f(\varphi(t,2\pi)) - f(\varphi(t,0))\right) \ dt $$
Here, further information on $f$ would be needed to continue in a meaningful way.

Thank you very much for the elaborated answer.  It addresses precisely my doubt. But it raises the question if there is a way to treat the function $\frac{1}{t^2}\partial_\theta f$ without being in coordinates or am I forced to write in coordinates due to the embedding? I am concerned with the coefficient $\frac{1}{t^2}$ because it changes if I extand the volume form or not.

The function is written in terms of coordinates, so I dont see a way out. What do you mean by extending the volume form? The multilinear form changes at every point as the parametrization "distorts" volumes more with increasing $t$, just like the integrand changes.

I am sorry. I wanted to say "expand". But, in any case, it does not matter because I understand it better now. Thank you very much!
